# DATEDIFF function in SQL Server - executes differently in different cases

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am using SQL Server and just identify one problem in my case. 
I have used the DATEDIFF function as:

```
select datediff(dd,'1935-12-07','2010-03-02')/365.00  ---> 74.28
select datediff(dd,'1935-12-07','2010-03-02')/365     ---> 74
select datediff(yy,'1935-12-07','2010-03-02')         ---> 75
```

If you can observe that If I try DATEDIFF with 'dd' then I get the difference as 74/74.28.
But If I use it with 'yy' I get the diference as 75.

Why this is so? Means Why the difference came as 75 as it nearly approximate to 74.

I need this both function in different cases. But as it is behaving differently I am facing a lot of problems.

Suggest me some solution to this.

Thanks.

Comment: The key phrase to understanding how `DATEDIFF()` works is at the beginning of the [manual](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms189794.aspx "DATEDIFF (Transact-SQL)"): *Returns the count (signed integer) of the **specified datepart boundaries crossed** between the specified startdate and enddate.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First case = You're implicitly casting to a float, shows the correct result

Second case = You're implictly casting to an int, which rounds down as part of the conversion (Floor value)

Third case = You're not casting anything at all, and `DATEDIFF()` returns a signed int, which rounds up (Ceiling value)

Solution: Do whatever you want, but keep it consistent throughout your code.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Thats fine with the behaviour of rounding to ceiling value. 
But if I try like this: select round(datediff(dd,'1935-12-07','2010-03-02')/365.00,0), I still get the 74. Then how it comes 75 with 'yy'.
Thats what my question is?

Answer (score 1):

The `datediff` function checks for the difference of the *date part you have specified*, so it is correct in saying the difference in the year part of the two dates is 75.

Or to word it as the folks at microsoft do, it counts the number of boundaries crossed of that datepart.  There are 75 year-boundaries crossed between the two dates in your example.

Have a look at [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms189794%28v=SQL.105%29.aspx) msdn page, it explains how it is supposed to work.